# Error 1064 cuando contenido de campos incluye acentos

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando hacer un update de campos de una tabla en mysql, y cuando los campos tienen acentos, me muestra mensajes de error en la sintaxis de sql.

```
sql = 'UPDATE resultados set %s = %s WHERE id_resultados = %s;'
 campos = columns[f][0],normalizar(r[f]),r[0]
 #print (sql,campos)
 rs.execute(sql,campos)
 base.connection.commit()
```

> 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''E_1_8' = 'ALMER═A' WHERE id_resultados = 1787' at line 1")

" tendría que ser ALMERÍA"

Al inicio del código ya tengo puesto `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf-8')`, y la tabla también tiene UTF8.

¿Cómo lo solucionáis vosotros?

Comment: ¿Estás pasándole a tu string de conexión de base de datos el _charset_ utf8?

Comment: No lo tenia, pero lo he puesto y sigue el error, además he confirmado que la tabla y los campos tengan utf8_bin, con el mismo mensaje de error.

Comment: Pregunta tonta ¿has comprobado que el error solo surge cuando el campo tiene acentos? Igual el error está en otra parte... Y por otro lado ¿qué hace la función `normalizar()`?

Comment: El proceso es para eso precisamente, para corregir las palabras que están sin acento. La función normalizar, busca en una tabla la palabra, si existe, mal escrita y devuelve, la correcta (con acento). La tabla resultados, es de quiniela, contiene, entre otras cosas, los nombres de los equipos de futbol, por eso la función normalizar busca en la tabla en el campo mal, el equipo ALMERIA, y en el campo bien, devuelve, ALMERÍA.

Answer (score 2):

La idea de usar parámetros en las *queries* es facilitar que la base de datos optimize la query, sobre todo si se va a usar varias veces.

En tu caso, la query:

```sql
UPDATE resultados set %s = %s WHERE id_resultados = %s;
```

Date cuenta que el primer parámetro es el nombre de un campo de la tabla, lo que tiene dos incovenientes:

- La base de datos no podrá optimizar la query porque desconoce el campo que usará la query
- El nombre de campo aparecerá con comillas, como si fuera una cadena de texto (eg: `SET 'CAMPO' = 'VALOR'`), que es el error que te da, nada qué ver con los acentos.

La solución pasa por hacer el proceso por separado, contruyeno la query por un lado, y ejecutándola con los valores que sean:

```py
campo = columns[f][0]
sql = f'UPDATE resultados set {campo} = %s WHERE id_resultados = %s;'
valores = (normalizar(r[f]), r[0])
rs.execute(sql, valores)
base.connection.commit()
```

Comment: @Jose la f delante de la cadena representa a un [_f-string_](/a/429851).

Comment: Ok, leo enlace, es lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

Después de infinidad de webs, pruebas y consejos (gracias) he dado con la solución, la pongo, mejor que explicarla porque no conozco las palabras técnicas.

```
sql = 'UPDATE resultados set %s = "%s" WHERE id_resultados = %s;' % (columns[f][0],eq,r[0])
```

columns, contiene el nombre de la columna a actualizar que lo obtengo de una select anterior.
eq, es el valor que quiero actualizar.
id_resultados, pues eso, el id del registro.

Saludos.-

Comment: Yo recomiendo [la solución ofrecida por ChemaCortes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/509402/158880), ya que la posibilidad de que haya una inyección sql en dicha solución es menor.

Comment: En tu solución por ejemplo, si el campo r[0] contiene el valor `1 or true`, el where quedaría así `WHERE id_resultados = 1 or true`, haciendo que el update afecte a toda la tabla.

Comment: Os agradezco las soluciones, y tomaré buena nota de ello, porque ... estoy aprendiendo. la f delante del update, ¿para que sirve?, la "mia" es el indice de un for. Muchas gracias

Comment: Esa f convierte una cadena en un f-string. Dentro de un f-string puedes poner expresiones de Python entre llaves. Un ejemplo sería `f"a+1 es {a+1}"`. Mas info en esta pagina: https://platzi.com/blog/f-strings-en-python/